# keep checkbox checked after page loaded by fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm looking for a way to keep the checkbox checked after loading the page, what I'm doing below is, I have a table with names, I would like if the users checked the checkbox, then it will update the table in the database and do sorting then back again to refresh the page, also if the user unchecked the checkbox, it will go again and update the database and reload the page again .. but here when I checked the checkbox the page automatically reloaded and it's unchecked the checkbox.

How could I keep it checked until the user unchecked it?

```js
function check(){
        let checkstatus = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
        for(let i = 0; i < checkstatus.length; i++){
            let checkedID = checkstatus[i].getAttribute("data-checked");
            checkstatus[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
                if(checkstatus[i].checked){
                    let url  = "update.php?checked=" + checkedID;
                    fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
                        .then(response => response.text())
                        .then(bringnames)
                    checkstatus[i].checked = true;
                }else if(!checkstatus[i].checked){
                    let url  = "update.php?unchecked=" + checkedID;
                    fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
                        .then(response => response.text())
                        .then(bringnames)
                }
            });
        }
    }
  
    function bringnames(){
    let url = "bringnames.php";
    fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function(data){
    console.log("Hello");
    })  
    }
```

Comment: If you refresh the page after you get your ajax response, then you missed the point of using ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localStorage to store the checkbox status  and after refresh the page you can get the status from localStorage.

Exemple:
Before refresh you save the checkboxStatus :

```
localStorage.setItem('checkboxStatus', true)
```

After refresh:

```
const checkboxStatus =  localStorage.getItem('checkboxStatus')
```